# Position and Sizing of Drop Down Menu in Polymer

Tags: css, polymer, paper-elements

I am learning Polymer. I like a lot of things about it. However, when it comes to styling items, I find it a bit complicated. Currently, I'm trying to style a drop down list and I can't seem to do a basic thing. I've created a [Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ae3diQIHHnxmrRGtDjK6?p=preview). The code looks like this:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Team">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Broncos</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Panthers</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Patriots</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

I am trying to make the drop down arrow (v) appear next to the text of the selected item instead of at the far right of the dropdown menu. In addition, I'm trying to make the listbox that appears the width of the container and positioned properly. However, I'm not having any luck. I've tried adding padding and margins to the dropdown-content class without any luck.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I don't understand the part about the dropdown arrow. Are you referring to positioning it next to the selected item when the menu is open?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'positioned properly'? If you look at [the paper-dropdown demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-dropdown-menu), there are a lot of options

Comment: @DanSchnau, I'm referring to the position of the arrow next to the item when the menu is closed. I'm trying to place the "v" right next to the text of the item when menu is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding those style tags to `div` add it to `paper-dropdown-menu`, it should work. for me its not working on IE

```
paper-dropdown-menu{
     background-color:silver;
     padding-left:48px;
     padding-right:48px;
      width:124px;
   }
```

I've created a [Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PX5VbsF9AM3h4mVT3d4f?p=preview)

Comment: I looked at the Plunk. Unfortunately, the plunk does match the contents of the question. In fact, the Plunk looks very similar to the item I posted.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the demo on [paper-dropdown-menu](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-dropdown-menu) you can see they centre the text using text-align. Therefore be changing it to text-align:right; It aligns with the arrow.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
paper-dropdown-menu {
  --paper-input-container-underline: {
    display: none;
  }
  --paper-input-container-label: {
    text-align: right;
  }
  paper-item {
    --paper-item-selected-weight: 400;
    --paper-item-focused-before: {
      background: #fff;
    }
  }
}
```

[Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zl2oQ6fgZqLeJSlcUHYu?p=preview)

Comment: I do not believe the problem is the alignment. I believe the problem is with the width of the `iron-input` or the layout approach of the `label-and-input-container`. I think its the latter. Yet, I can't figure out how to change it. It seems like the label-and-input-container flex's to fill the allotted space. Then, the down arrow is placed after this element. If I could figure out a way to either a) make the `label-and-input-container` not flex or b) make the width of the `iron-input` dynamic instead of what it defaults to, I think it would work. I just need help getting there.